Why can't I call this lambda function?
Below is a simplified version of the section of code that's causing the problem:
void reorient(C new_pos) {

  // Orientate north
  if (pos + 0x10 == new_pos) {
    if ((orient == 0) && (Gz < 0.1 || Gz > 2 * PI - 0.1)) return;
    auto disoriented = []() {return Gz < PI;};
    orient = 0;

  // Orientate east
  } else if (pos + 0x01 == new_pos) {
    if ((orient == 1) && (abs(Gz - HALF_PI) < 0.1)) return;
    auto disoriented = []() {return Gz < HALF_PI || Gz > 3 * HALF_PI;};
    orient = 1;

  // Orientate south
  } else if (pos - 0x10 == new_pos) {
    if ((orient == 2) && (abs(Gz - PI) < 0.1)) return;
    auto disoriented = []() {return Gz > PI;};
    orient = 2;

  // Orientate west
  } else {
    if ((orient == 3) && (abs(Gz - HALF_PI * 3) < 0.1)) return;
    auto disoriented = []() {return Gz > HALF_PI && Gz < 3 * HALF_PI;};
    orient = 3;
  }

  disoriented();
}

For some reason, I get the compilation error:
Compilation error: 'disoriented' was not declared in this scope

Gz, PI, HALF_PI and pos are all global variables (I'm using arduino).
This error disappears when I move disoriented() inside each if statement, and disoriented() isn't called anywhere else in the code. What's wrong?

You can't use a variable outside the scope you declare it in.

disoriented is a lambda function declared within each of the if-else clauses, please read the full code before commenting.

I did.  You declared it inside the if/else statements.  That means you can't then use it outside those if else statements.

Why so, and how would I work around this?

This is the way C++ works, its always been like this.  To fix it you have to move where you declare disoriented to the same scope where you use it.  For lambda expressions this is hard to do so most people use a std::function<ret_t,(params_t)> as the type of the variable and then assign to that the lambda you want to use

Make a single function pointer variable outside the ifs, and assign the lambdas to it. (std::function would work instead of the function pointer, but it's excessive here and has overhead).

Ok thanks, I'm new to c++ so the way the scopes work surrounding the if statements is confusing to me, but I'll probably just restructure the function. Thanks.

You are declaring a separate lambda instance inside of each if/else block.  They are all going out of scope before you try to call any of them.  There is no disoriented variable present in the scope where you are trying to invoke it.
To do what you are attempting, you need to declare disoriented as its own variable before the first if.  But, since each lambda is a different compiler-generated type, you will have to declare disoriented as a single type that can handle them all. You can use either std::function or a function pointer (since none of your lambdas are capturing values), eg:
#include functional>

void reorient(C new_pos) {

  std::function<void()> disoriented;

  // Orientate north
  if (pos + 0x10 == new_pos) {
    ...
    disoriented = []() {return Gz < PI;};
    ...

  // Orientate east
  } else if (pos + 0x01 == new_pos) {
    ...
    disoriented = []() {return Gz < HALF_PI || Gz > 3 * HALF_PI;};
    ...

  // Orientate south
  } else if (pos - 0x10 == new_pos) {
    ...
    disoriented = []() {return Gz > PI;};
    ...

  // Orientate west
  } else {
    ...
    disoriented = []() {return Gz > HALF_PI && Gz < 3 * HALF_PI;};
    ...
  }

  disoriented();
}

Or:
void reorient(C new_pos) {

  void (*disoriented)();

  // Orientate north
  if (pos + 0x10 == new_pos) {
    ...
    disoriented = +[]() {return Gz < PI;};
    ...

  // Orientate east
  } else if (pos + 0x01 == new_pos) {
    ...
    disoriented = +[]() {return Gz < HALF_PI || Gz > 3 * HALF_PI;};
    ...

  // Orientate south
  } else if (pos - 0x10 == new_pos) {
    ...
    disoriented = +[]() {return Gz > PI;};
    ...

  // Orientate west
  } else {
    ...
    disoriented = +[]() {return Gz > HALF_PI && Gz < 3 * HALF_PI;};
    ...
  }

  (*disoriented)();
}

